# ng-paste not reaching scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to upload images from clipboard, but the ng-paste is not reaching the $scope.paste function, it reaches the controller, but not the scope.

Function:

```
$scope.paste = function (event) {
                var clipData = event.clipboardData;
                angular.forEach(clipData.items, function (item, key) {
                    if (clipData.items[key]['type'].match(/image.*/)) {
                    // if it is a image
                    var img = clipData.items[key].getAsFile();
                    console.log('A image sized ' + img.size + ' is being   uploaded.');
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('file', img);

                    $http.post("engine/controller/system/upload.php", fd, {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': undefined
                        }
                    }).success(function (data, url) {

                        if (data.status == 'success') {
                            //Success
                            toastr.success(data.status_msg, data.title);
                            $location.path("/image/"+data.image_id);

                        } else {
                            //Not Successful
                            toastr.error(data.status_msg, data.title);
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
            };
```

Trigger:

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-paste="paste($event)">Activate    Paste!</button>
```

I don't know if it matters, but I am also using routes and the trigger is located in a template file. (index.tpl).

Comment: <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="pasteCTRL">
 
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-paste="paste($event)">Activate Paste!</button>
 </div>

Comment: "it reaches the controller, but not the scope" What does this mean? How did you determine this?